# Intersection between invariant curves for a map that coming from an autonomus vector field.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, invariant-subspace, set-invariance

Consider the system of differential equation

$$\dot x = f(x) $$
with $x\in{M}$ where $f$ is a function of the only $x$, so the system is autonomus.
Now let $\phi^t(x)$ be the flow of the system, that is the solution at time $t$ with initial condition $x(0)=x$.

Fixing a time $\tau$ one can consider the map

$$\phi^\tau: x\in M\rightarrow \phi^\tau(x) \in M$$.

So one can consider the sequence ${x_k}$ defined by $x_k= \phi^{k\tau}(x_0)$ given $x_0\in M$. This is called orbit.

An invariant set $D$ is a set such that $\phi^\tau(D) \subseteq D$.

My question is: given two invariant curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ for the map above, can these $\gamma_1$ intersect $\gamma_2$? I know that this is true in general for a map, but what happen if the map coming from a time independent vector field, as in this case? I think that this is not true ( there's no intersection ) in view the property of the phase space of autonomus ODE: for any $x_0$ in $M$ there exists only one solution passing through this point.

In the notes of my teacher i read this sentence: " intersection between two invariant curve cannot happen for that map which comes from the discretization of flow of vector field independent with respect to time". So, is this sentence wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can happen: as a trivial counterexample imagine zero vector field, ie. nothing moves at all. Then the time-$\tau$ map $\phi^\tau$ is the identity for any $\tau$ so any curve is an invariant curve for the map and you are free to choose whatever you want as your two invariant curves.

But it is a very common intutiton to think the opposite.
The problem is that one tends to imagine considered invariant curves as orbits of the flow $\phi$ and for these the statement obviously holds, more precisely, in general, two orbits of a flow are either identical or disjoint. This is still true for the orbits of any time-$\tau$ map because it is a homeomorphism but an invariant set for this map consists, in principle, of many orbits of the map.

It is not that difficult to construct also nontrivial examples: think, for example, about a flow on an infinite horizontal tube (cylinder) with constant unit speed in horizontal direction. Then take as the first invariant curve any horizontal line on the tube. Now fix any $\tau$ (eg. $\tau = 1$) and construct the second invariant curve in such a way that it wraps around the tube and does one revolution in exactly time $\tau$.

Comment: Thank you @RomanHric . So the non trivial example you said comes from considering an autonomus vector field ( vector field independent with respect to time ) ? In the notes of my teacher i read this sentence: " intersection between two invariant curve cannot happen for that map which comes from the discretization of flow of vector field independent with respect to time". So, is this sentence wrong?

Comment: A precise definition of what is meant by an invariant curve is crucial here. If it is as above, that you fix a time, take the corresponding homeomorphism, and any invariant set shaped as curve is an invariant curve, then it does not hold. But if you, eg. require the curve to be invariant for all time-maps or the flow itself, then it is correct. I believe it is meant in this sense - you consider invariant curves of the flow and then you apply a chosen time-map and then it is correct.

Comment: Just to add to previous remark: in the tube example the only "true" invariant sets thus would be horizontal lines. The ones going around the tube are obviously invariant only for special times-maps and definitely not for the flow itself.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what do you mean. You mean: the sentence of my teacher is correct if one requires the curve to be invariant for all time-maps. But in the case that one fix a time the sentence is wrong and a counter example is your tube example. Right?

Comment: Right. The easiest counterexamples are probably those with $\phi^\tau$ the identity map. One can get these easily also from non-zero vector fields, eg. consider the rotation of the plane around the origin by unit angle speed. Then $\phi^{2\pi} = id$.

Comment: It would all make much more sense for "integral" instead of "invariant" curves. As I think about it now, if we consider zero vector field (I implicitly ruled that out for no good reason) then nothing above about invariant curves (defined as just invariant sets of a special form) work because any set is invariant - everything sits on its place forever.

Comment: Ok, very helpful, thanks a lot.

Comment: One last (class of) example(s) to show that just being invariant does not work. This is nice because it is easy, common, non-degenerate. Take a linear system on the plane given by a diagonal matrix (choosing the two values on the diagonal one can moreover get various properties of the system). Now $x$-axis and $y$-axis are invariant sets-curves for the flow intersecting obviously at the origin (but not integral curves - each one being the union of three orbits of the flow).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110128/discussion-between-giovanni-febbraro-and-roman-hric).

Comment: Sure, thanks for this further argument. However, remains true that no intersection can exists between two invariant curves for a all-time map, if this map comes from an autonomus vector field.